# Processing a complex object by http get in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, angular6, rxjs6

I do not understand how to handle the object I subscribe to. The object is the following structure:

```
{
  data:{
       date: "2018-02-20 13:10:23",
       text: "Описание",
       id: 1,
       items: [
              0: {
                 date: "2018-02-20 13:10:23",
                 text: "Описание",
                 images: [
                         0: "image1.jpg",
                         1: "image2.jpg"
                         ],
                 name: "Изображения",
                 type: "images"
                 },
              1: {
                 date: "2018-02-20 13:10:23",
                 text: "Описание",
                 image: null,
                 type: "video",
                 url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/v64KOxKVLVg"
                 }
              ]
       }
}
```

I make an appeal through the service:

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class VideoService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getVideoTape() {
        return this.http.get(`http://ip_adress/api/v1/mixed_galleries/1`);
    }
}
```

There is an interface model:

```
export class VideoListModel {
    constructor(
        public created_at: string,
        public description: string,
        public id: number,
        public items: any[],
        public name: string
    ) {}
}
```

And I do the processing in the component:

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable, Subscription} from 'rxjs';
import {filter} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {VideoService} from '../shared/services/video.service';
import {VideoListModel} from '../../shared/models/video-list.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-video-index',
  templateUrl: './video-index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./video-index.component.scss']
})

export class VideoIndexComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private videoTape = [];
    private _subscription2: Subscription;

    constructor( private videoService: VideoService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this._subscription2 = this.videoService.getVideoTape()
          .subscribe((data: VideoListModel[]) => {
          this.videoTape = data;
          console.log(this.videoTape);
      });
  }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this._subscription2.unsubscribe();
    }

}
```

The task is to make a selection from objects by type: "video". Through AJAX + jQuery did it without problems, and in Angular I'm relatively new. Shoveled a bunch of video lessons yesterday, but nowhere are examples of filtering such complex objects.

Construction:

```
this._subscription2 = this.videoService.getVideoTape()
          .pipe(filter((data: VideoListModel[]) => data.items.type === 'video'))
          .subscribe((data: any) => {
              this.videoTape = data.data;
              console.log(this.videoTape);
          });
```

does not work. The result is an error saying "Property 'items' does not exist on type 'VideoListModel []'". Intuitively, I understand that the matter is most likely in the interface, but I can not understand how to modify the interface so that the filtering works correctly. If someone encountered filtering complex objects, tell me please how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have an array of VideoModels but an array of `items` in an object. Piping the whole content to a filter lets you filter items out of arrays, but you have an object. You could try the following workaround:

Create an interface like this

```js
interface Item {
  date: Date;
  text: string;
  images: string[];
  name: string;
  type: string;
}

export interface VideoModel {
  data: {
    date: Date;
    text: string;
    id: number;
    items: Item[];
  }
}
```

Then you can use HttpClient in your Service as follows

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
[...]

getVideoTape(): Observable<VideoModel> {
  return this.http.get<VideoModel>(url).pipe(
    map(model => {
      const items = model.data.items.filter(item => item.type === 'video');
      model.data.items = items;
      return model;
    }),
    catchError(error => console.error(error))
  );
}
```

Pay attention to your images array, as it isn't valid json, string[]? Wouldn't it be better to filter the types serverside in order to reduce traffic?

Comment: Very-Big-Thank You! It's work! As I suspected, the problem was in the interface. Answering your question about valid json: the database is on the server side and I do not have the opportunity to adjust its architecture. And that means " filter the types serverside in order", I do not know) I'm not so experienced yet, apparently)

Comment: Oh, I understood what you're talking about. In my subject it's not json-file. It's just a copy from console Chrome, when I return data with console.log() :)

Comment: You are welcome! If you have no access to the server, and the server does not provide a type-filter you will probably have to implement a client-side filter. If you have access to an interface for the server it may provide some url params for filtering. Http get requests do or should always append additional data to url like for example `http://yoururl.com/pathto/yourentity/?type=video`.

Answer (score 1):

your json data is not valid.

it should be

```
{
"data":{
     "date": "2018-02-20 13:10:23",
     "text": "tt",
     "id": 1,
     "items": [
            {
               "date": "2018-02-20 13:10:23",
               "text": "Описание",
               "images": [
                       "image1.jpg",
                       "image2.jpg"
                       ],
               "name": "Изображения",
               "type": "images"
               },
            {
               "date": "2018-02-20 13:10:23",
               "text": "Описание",
               "image": null,
               "type": "video",
               "url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/v64KOxKVLVg"
               }
            ]
     }
}
```

then going to http://json2ts.com/

your model would be

```
export interface Item {
    date: string;
    text: string;
    images: string[];
    name: string;
    type: string;
    image?: any;
    url: string;
}

export interface Data {
    date: string;
    text: string;
    id: number;
    items: Item[];
}

export interface VideotapeAnswer {
    data: Data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You say that `data` is an `array` of type `VideoListModel`, the array of cause has no property `items`. What you did is like `Array.items.type` which does not make sense. There are probably more fancy solutions but try mapping your result array to an observable where you can use your filters on.

```
this._subscription2 = this.videoService.getVideoTape()
.pipe(
    map(data => from(data).pipe(filter((d: VideoListModel) => d.items.type === 'video')))
    tap(data => data.subscribe(d => {
        this.videoTape.push(d);
    }))
).subscribe();
```

Additionally map your data like this when using angular version 4+

```
getVideoTape() {
    return this.http.get<VideoListModel[]>(`http://ip_adress/api/v1/mixed_galleries/1`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the changes suggested by @Piero and your service is not returning any observable.

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class VideoService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getVideoTape():Observable<any>  {
        return this.http.get(`http://ip_adress/api/v1/mixed_galleries/1`);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution destroys types. Check out my answer to prevent this.

Comment: Yes, it is not returning according to type in services I just told to add this code to work for him. Again if he wanted to refactor he can do that. By the way thanks for your comment.@ngfelixl